# Clicking on an image in RecycleView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am really new to AndroidStudio and I'm trying to make a sharing app. My purpose is to have an app that automatically loads up all the images on my phone(or in my phone's gallery, not that important) and display them on screen. Afterwards, I want to click on one of the images over there, and then use a **Share** button I made to send that photo to another person (it can be an MMS or any other application, the main problem is that this share button transmit **the picture I clicked on most recently**).

I don't know a lot about the specifics of Android Studio, meaning I know how to code (sort of) but I am unfamiliar with the possibilities of implementing this. My code is below.

GalleryAdapter.java:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<String> images;
protected PhotoListener photoListener;

public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<String> images, PhotoListener photoListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
    this.photoListener = photoListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false)
    );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String image=images.get(position);
    Glide.with(context).load(image).into(holder.image);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            photoListener.onPhotoClick(image);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}

public interface PhotoListener{
    void onPhotoClick(String path);
}
}
```

ImagesGallery.java:

```
public class ImagesGallery {
    public static ArrayList<String> listofImages(Context context){
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
        ArrayList<String> listofAllImages=new ArrayList<>();
        String absolutePathOfImage;
        uri= MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection={MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};
        String orderBy= MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy+" DESC");
        column_index_data=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            absolutePathOfImage=cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            listofAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
        }
        return listofAllImages;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter;
    List<String> images;
    TextView gallery_number;
    private static final int MY_READ_PERMISSION_CODE=101;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gallery_number=findViewById(R.id.gallery_number);
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_gallery_images);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_READ_PERMISSION_CODE);
    } else {
        loadImages();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.share_menu){
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri uriToImage=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.tutorialpaper5/"+R.drawable.test);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.app_name)));
    } else{
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}

private void loadImages(){
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
    images=ImagesGallery.listofImages(this);
    galleryAdapter=new GalleryAdapter(this, images, new GalleryAdapter.PhotoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPhotoClick(String path) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
    gallery_number.setText("Photos +("+images.size()+")");

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode==MY_READ_PERMISSION_CODE){
        if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "read external storage permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            loadImages();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Read external storage permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

You will notice that in my onOptionsItemSelected class I just threw in a picture I had in the drawable directory to see if the share button actually works. It does, now I just need some way for it memorize my last clicked photo and throw it in that Intent. But again, I am not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options, here are two simple solutions just to link your code parts.

**Suggestion with minimal changes in your logic:**

You can just save the `onPhotoClick(String path)` to a field that will defined in the activity class scope and then use this field in the `onOptionsItemSelected` adding some code parts:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String clickedImagePath = null
// ...
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.share_menu){
       if (clickedImagePath  != null) {
         // The code you had for sharing with changing line for uriToImage
         Uri uriToImage=Uri.parse(clickedImagePath);
       } else { 
         // maybe show some error than nothing selected
       }
    }
}

// ...
        public void onPhotoClick(String path) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            clickedImagePath = path
        }
// ...
```

**Maybe a better UX**

Remove the `onOptionsItemSelected` completely and move the intent code to the `onPhotoClick` listener.

```
    @Override
    public void onPhotoClick(String path) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri uriToImage=Uri.parse(path); // <-- Don't forget to fix the path
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.app_name)));

    }
```

Comment: Ok, I edited my code according to your first suggestion and it worked! Now after I click on a certain photo and use the share button to add it to Google Maps for example, it will link it. Then I can go back and click on another one and it will link that one. Though it won't actually let me upload anywhere. Even when trying via Messages, now it will say 'Couldn't load attachments.". Before when I gave it a photo from the drawable directory at random it worked. But at the end of the day, the clicking on one of the photos and being able to kind of share it was the main issue.

Comment: Check the path and if the stream data are passed correctly as it did with static path. If you correct the intent  the way other apps expect it it will load!

Comment: I think maybe there is another issue because I found A LOT of people complaining about URIs saying that there is a big chance other apps will not recognize them(or something like that) when trying to send files through it. And most people recommend using a FileProvider and/or ContentProvider. For me it's acceptable for now. In the future, I will further develop the application to also share documents and other stuff, and I'll probably need to implement them then. Now I was just making a "demo" sort of.